# Excel WorksheetFunction.Vlookup is giving inconsistent results

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Community,
I am working with very large Excel Workbooks (3200 lines of VBA, 127,536 KB).
The goal is to determine if there are drawing number conflicts across/within corporate divisions.
The Workbook contains worksheets(currently 5) that represent corporate divisions reserved drawing number lists.

Each Worksheet contains drawing numbers where the Worksheet can have between 50,000 to 200,000 rows and 2 to 5 columns that are formatted as text. I'm only using the first row at the moment.

The lists can contain drawing numbers like the following and can be up to 24 alpha/numeric/specialChar:

"*38017"; "075242-DIV"; "00000006"; "208771*37820"; "4110535 (223)";
"AS-107774-03"; "ADS168/580760 (223)"

I'm using a Dell Precision 7770, I9, 64 gig Ram, 6 tb storage. The excel takes 15-20 seconds to load. When I do a run it takes about 35min. to process 449384 rows of data populating 4 columns in each row with results after apply 1 of approx 250 rule patterns based on length, special characters, creator, suffix, prefix, construction patterns, etc.

I'm using a function "IsItemNumberStrInNumLogWks" to see if a drawing number is being used by a division.
In this function I'm using "Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup" and its giving me inconsistent results. There are many times where "Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup" returns the "1004" when the value is definitely in the worksheet.

This issue is core to solving corporate drawing miss-alignment/conflict. Is there something I'm not applying correctly?
Thanks for the help!
Scott

```
Calling Code
Parameter values:
crntItemNumber = "22613900" :  gcNumLogNameTab = "Div1_Number_Log"
gcNumLogRangeDiv1 = "A2:B67113"


If IsItemNumberStrInNumLogWks(crntItemNumber, gcNumLogNameTab, gcNumLogRangeHTPG) Then .....

'=========================================================================================
' IsItemNumberStrInNumLogWks
' This checks to see if an item_number is in a divisions Number log worksheet
'===      Parameter Name              Object Type      Description
'           dwgNumStr                   String           drawing number Name; "1234-6789""
'           numLogTabName               String           the name of the worksheet tab; "Division_Number_Log"
'           strLogNumRange              String           the range of the Worksheet to be checked; "A2:B65878"
'
'=== Return:                            Boolean          If the dwg number pattern is found then return True
'

Public Function IsItemNumberStrInNumLogWks( _
  ByVal dwgNumStr As String, _
  ByVal numLogTabName As String. _
  ByVal strLogNumRange As String) As Boolean

    Dim numLogWks As Worksheet
    Dim numberLogRange As Range
    Dim numLogNumber As String: numLogNumber = "Not Found"
    'Dim dwgNumStr As String

    'dwgNumStr = "314545"  '314551 not found
         
    On Error GoTo SetAsFalse
    
    Set numLogWks = Worksheets(numLogTabName)
    Set numberLogRange = numLogWks.Range(strLogNumRange) '"A2:B65878"
    
    numLogNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(dwgNumStr, numberLogRange, 1, False)
    

SetAsFalse:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
       IsItemNumberStrInNumLogWks = False
      Else
       IsItemNumberStrInNumLogWks = True
    End If

End Function
```

Here is a data example as viewed notepad++ :
All 3 values can't be found by VLookup.

["Div1_Number_Log" data as seen in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWyTm.png)

```
[TAB] "Div1_Number_Log"
22613700    C/Z 6 BASE, PIPE DOWN
22613900    VENTURI SUPPORT RIGHT, ET-5H
22626600    ACCUMULATOR BASE
```

[All Parts All Divisions" data as seen in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdWSh.png)

```
[TAB] "All Parts All Divisions"
C/Z 6 BASE, PIPE DOWN   22613700    Component
VENTURI SUPPORT RIGHT, ET-5H    22613900    Component
ACCUMULATOR BASE    22626600    Component
```

If I create a new worksheet and use VLookup as a Formula the value is found as shown below: A3 = "22613900"

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,HTPG_Number_Log!$A$2:B$67113,1,FALSE),"Not Found")
```

[VLookup as a Formula. Same Data Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE9cm.png)

If I step through the code is get the error as shown below:

[Stepping through the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZVOL.png)

Thanks for the help. Scott

Comment: I'm afraid that no one can really help you as we don't have your data. Things you could check: Is the search term correct? Is the range correct? Are you looking into the correct workbook (you are currently using the sheet from active workbook, maybe that's not what you want). When you issue a `VLookup` as formula into the sheet, does it return a value? Contains your search string or your data leading or trailing blanks (or other invisible characters)?

Comment: Are you expecting it to search all columns in range strLogNumRange?  It won't,  it'll only search the first column

Comment: How exactly are you using this function? You're looking up a value to return `True/False`, to do what? To look up again to return a value from another column? That's doubling the number of operations. Please share the calling code so we can suggest improvements on all of it.

Comment: It is unlikely that Vlookup is giving inconsistent results. It is much more likely that your drawing numbers in the spreadsheet database (yuk!) are malformed and merely look like what you think they should. Find a concrete example where you get a 1004 for a known to be present drawing number and then examine the failing case **very** carefully, My guess is a leading or trailing space or I1l|/QO0/2Z/5S/B8 confusions will account for your phantom mismatches. Vlookup is most probably working correctly.

Comment: I added details to the description above:
1) Example Data (and Pics)
2) Formula based test of VLookup with the same data (Works as expected with Pic)
3) Step through data (and pic)
Thanks Scott

Comment: @chris neilsen : I'm only searching the first column at this point. I've used VLookup alot in other worksheet formulas.

Comment: @VBasic2008 : I'm testing to see if the Drawing number is in the Drawing number logs for a specific Division. If I find it (True) then I assign it to the Division in the main Function

Comment: @Martin : The data looks good. I've viewed it Notepad++ and TextPad 9. The data came out of Oracle ERP. Also all drawing numbers are Trimmed before being used at the beginning of the main function. In Some cases I convert to Uppercase before using StrComp. But in this case its all Numeric. Can you suggest another way to view the data?

Comment: There is also a possibility if they are pure numeric values that a few have been input as string value '1234 as opposed to numeric value 1234.

Comment: @Martin Brown OP says *"between 50,000 to 200,000 rows and 2 to 5 columns that are formatted as text"*.

Comment: @Martin Brown : I have set all columns to a format as text. This is due to leading zeros. General, in some cases, will remove the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

### Match (Lookup) Data

**The Calling Procedure**

```vb
Sub Test()

    If IsDrawingNumberFound(1234, "Sheet1") Then
        MsgBox "Found."
    Else
        MsgBox "Not!"
    End If

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function IsDrawingNumberFound( _
    ByVal DrawingNumber As String, _
    ByVal LogSheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(LogSheetName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    IsDrawingNumberFound = IsNumeric(Application.Match(DrawingNumber, rg, 0))

End Function
```

Comment: VBasic2008, I will take this apart to understand your approach and give a spin. Thanks

Comment: The code you provided worked and I understand how it works, but there are still anomalies. The are 3 values in the "Div1_Number_Log" worksheet as an example: 22613700; 22613900; 2626600. When I do a full run the code identifies 22613700 & 22613900 correctly but misses 2626600. I also have a Function that will run against a single row that I use for testing. If I run that single row it is identified correctly.  There seems to be a timing issue.

Comment: If you're using my function as is, show me how you call it for the value not found e.g. `IsDrawingNumberFound(2626600, "Sheet1")`.Maybe you have some white space there: check the length of the cell with e.g. `=LEN(A25)` and see if it returns 7 (characters). Maybe you're missing a digit (maybe it's `22620600`) since the other two numbers have 8 (digits). I've just noticed that you're talking about leading zeros in another of your comments as if it were no big deal. In your comments, read my first comment and then ask a new question because this whole idea is useless if it takes 30 minutes.

Comment: I'm doing a full run now. Also The time to run has doubled with the new code. I'm not concerned with runtime, I'm more concerned with quality; there is a lot riding on these results. I call it the exact same way. So it will be a while.   But .... Why does it work perfectly if I process the single row and not the bulk run? The Function I used for testing is identical to the bulk run Function. It does not loop through all rows. I specify the row to process. Can you suggest a way to test timing?

Comment: I also have a column that I set that shows how the "Created By Division" was Derived. So I maybe I can set that some how to monitor this case.

Answer (score 0):

VBasic2008
Chris Neilsen
Martin Brown
FunThomas

Thanks for all the help, Guidance and time.
I finally found the issue. The Excels I received from the division had the A column cells inconsistently populated with a hidden apostrophe. This is not detected by a Len() check and is not detected in NotePad++ and this is done by excel when a number is in a text field.
I did find how to remediate it by Copying the columns and pasting the cells to a new column via the Values '123' option.

Another facet to this entire experience was the fact that Microsoft has added an Excel feature called "Automatic Conversion"; File\Options\Data\Automatic Data Conversion. If this is enabled Excel will Automatically convert numeric Text (data Type 2) to a Number (data Type 1)  even if the Column Formatting is set to Text. This conversion happens when you paste into a cell or double clicking on a cell.

If you use VLookup from a formula Excel does not "seem" to look at the data Type, but the VBA version of VLookup does. So this is also something to watch out for.

Again thanks
Scott

Comment: The hidden apostrophe is not in the cell. It is a way of entering a cell value so that it becomes text. The data conversion is not new and is in fact very old. The format of the column has never affected the type of actual data in that column, and one always needed to re-enter the data in the cell after applying the format in order to bring it to the accordance with the format. VLookup has always considered strings and numbers different, both on the sheet and in the VBA code. So your problem lies in making sure the cells contain the right type of data, not in inconsistencies of VBA.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the clarification. I have never experienced the above issues in Excel before. If the apostrophe is not in the cell then where is it managed?

Comment: Sort of outside the cell, in the sense that it's not a part of the cell's `.Value`. My point was that you don't need to worry about it because this virtual apostrophe is not going to trip your vlookup. The difference in the data types will.

Comment: @GSerg I did experience that if VLookup was looking up "40-12345-02" and a Number Log Worksheet being searched contained the value "40-12345-02", and it had the apostrophe,  then VLookup did make the match. As soon as I removed the apostrophe the match was made. So this is what I experienced with very large Workbooks.

Comment: @GSerg Also you are correct in that if checked the Len() of the Number Log Worksheet value, the Len() did not include the apostrophe. However if I checked the type(), the value being searched for was type() = 2 (text). The Number Log Worksheet value, with the apostrophe had type() = 1 (number) and VLookup could not find it. As soon as I removed that apostrophe then the type() = 2 (text) VLookup could find it. This pattern took alot of hours to figure out. So if you have any other guidance/insight on how to deal with this issue I would appreciate it. Thanks...